# What would be the way to join these CTEs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Working on the following SQL code, I cannot seem to find  a way to properly join the 2 CTEs being created to get the right (or at least my expected) number of records.

TEST 1 & TEST 2 just return the records each CTE independently produces; ***n*** & ***m***, respectively.

I was expecting to be able to retrieve ***n*** records by using either TEST 3 (a LEFT JOIN), or TEST 4 (an INNER JOIN) however, no matter what type of join I use (and I've tried all equijoins); I keep getting ***m*** records.

```
WITH
CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS AS
(
    SELECT
            InspectorId,
            InspectionetailId
            ...
        FROM ...
        WHERE ...
),

CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
            InspectorId,
            COUNT(InspectionDetailId) Inspections
        FROM CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS
        GROUP BY InspectorId
)

/*
TEST 1:
*/
/*
    SELECT * FROM CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS
*/

/*
TEST 2:
*/
/*
    SELECT * FROM CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS
*/

/*
TEST 3:
*/
/*
    SELECT
            CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS.*,
            CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS.Inspections
        FROM
            CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS
            LEFT JOIN CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS
                ON CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS.InspectorId = CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS.InspectorId
*/

/*
TEST 4:
*/
/*
    SELECT
            CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS.*,
            CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS.Inspections
        FROM
            CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS
            INNER JOIN CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS
                ON CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS.InspectorId = CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS.InspectorId
*/
```

How can I get the records I want? or How else can I join these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your TEST 3, but make the ...Inspections your leftmost query:

```
SELECT CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS.*
    , CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS.Inspections 
FROM CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS
    LEFT JOIN CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS
        ON CTE_ALL_INSPECTIONS.InspectorId = CTE_ALL_INSPECTORS.InspectorId
```

This says, "give me all the inspections, as well as any counts from Inspectors that exist".